# The Science of Installation

Tags: deployment, installation, cross-platform, upgrade

I have minimal exposure to RPM, Windows installer mechanics, and WIX.  That said, I'm interested in making a cross-platform installer tool (Linux, Windows) that supports upgrading and downgrading (versiona and patches) of my own product.  I don't believe this is a topic to be approached lightly;  I would like to learn the science of the art (or the art of the science).  If I succeed, and build a minimally successful installer tool, it would have these features:

- does not depend on a platform-specific tool (such as Windows Installer).
- reads XML or a declarative syntax to fulfill installation requirements.
- attempts to minimize steps to upgrade or downgrade one of my products (rather than requiring a complete uninstall and re-install).
- does not require knowledge of interim product versions, in order to jump versions (i.e. can upgrade one of my products from version 1 to version 3, without passing through version 2).

I'm convinced that "the key" to achieving this goal is by seeing versions as a "point A to point B" problem, which implies that A and B are described by two XML "version" documents that hold info about all the parts and actions (files, or platform specifics such as registry entries).  My installer tool would "join" or compare the two documents and determine a minimal set of changes to transform A into B.  To some extent, I believe this is precisely what Windows Installer does.

Of course there are further complexities, but that is the point of this post.  Where is "the bible" of information on this topic?  Remember, I want to make my own installer - not use a platform-specific one.  For those who care, my products are usually written in C++ or C#.

Or perhaps I should study something like [Steam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valve_Steam) which is cross-platform and has "automated game updates" as part of its capabilities.  In my case, the problem of online deployment is already handled.  It is just the final installation step I'm examining.  Does Steam use native installers (such as an MSI)?  If yes, then that is not what I'm looking for.

In short, what path should I pursue to become somewhat competent on the science of this topic?

Comment: Incidentally, Steam usually handles installation itself (At least on windows) unless the game in question was non-steam and already has an installer in which case it downloads/uses that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert and others can give you better answers but...

Don't declaratively list steps required to install your product - You'll end up making assumptions which will eventually prove wrong. Instead, you should be looking at defining the final state of the installation and let the installer worry about how to make that happen.

Another consideration is that being downgradable may involve huge complications depending on your product - Would it have to down-grade database schemas / file formats / ??? In short, every version of your app will need to be both fully forwards- and backwards-compatible (or at least fail gracefully). Also consider the scenario where V1 of your app stores settings in a file. V2 comes along and adds more settings. You downgrade to V1 - What should it do when changing settings? preserve the V2 settings? dump them? Do some of the V2 settings change the impact/meaning of the V1 settings? Are these decisions to be made by your app or your installer?

Anyway, all that aside, I'd say you need at the least:

- A central server/farm with complete files for every version of your App and some API/Web Service which allows the installer to retrieve files/filesets/??? as appropriate (You may be able to tie this into a source control system like svn)
- Some way of specifying the desired post-install state of the system in an environment-agnostic way (Think install paths - `/usr/???` - should the map to `C:\Users\???` or `C:\Program Files` on windows? Also don't forget it might be a 64-bit machine so it could be `C:\Program Files (x86)`.
- A very clever installer written for multiple platforms with as much code re-use as possible (Java, Mono, ???)

The installer should do (simply):

- Determine the desired version of the product.
- Download/read the appropriate manifest.
- Compare the desired situation with the current situation (NB: What is currently on the local system, NOT what *should* be on the system according to the current version's manifest)
- Generate a list of steps to reconcile the two, taking into account any dependencies (can't set file permissions before you copy the file). You can make use of checksums/hashing/similar to compare existing files with desired files - thus only downloading the files actually required.
- Possibly take complete backups
- Download/unpack required files.
- Download/unpack 3rd party dependencies - Later .Net Framework Version/Similar
- Perform install steps in atomic a manner as possible (at the very least keeping a record of steps taken so they can be undone)
- Potentially apply any version-jump specific changes (up/down-grade db, config files, etc.)
- verify installation as much as possible (checksums again)

None of this addresses the question of what to do when the installer itself needs upgrading.

A technique I've used on Windows is that the installer executable itself is little more than a wrapper with some interfaces which loads the actual installer dynamically at runtime - thus I can move files about/unload/reload assemblies, etc... from within a fixed process that almost never changes.

As I said above, I am definitely not an expert, just a novice who's done some of this myself. I sure you can get more complete answers from others but I hope this helped a little